# Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor not releasing memory even after calling shutdown

Tags: spring, multithreading, memory-management, out-of-memory, threadpoolexecutor

I am using Springs ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in my project for thread Pools.

As part of different unit tests, I start these thread Pools, run tests and then shutdown the thread Pools. However, writing bunch of test cases is causing Out of Memory Issues. Tried debugging it using Memory Analyzer.

Seems that shutdown() method does not release memory and as a result initialization in next test case keeps on increasing the memory until it runs out of space.

Question=> How to effectively release memory consumed by thread Pools.

Please note that shutdown() does cause threads to die.

Some code snapshots

```
  @BeforeEach
  public void configure(){
    customThreadPoolExecutor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    customThreadPoolExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
    customThreadPoolExecutor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(5);
    customThreadPoolExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false);
    visibilityThreadPoolExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false);
    visibilityThreadPoolExecutor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(5);
    monitoringThreadPoolTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false);
    monitoringThreadPoolTaskExecutor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(5);
  }
```

```
 @AfterEach
  public void shutDownThreadPools() throws InterruptedException {
workerMessageMap.clear();
customThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
visibilityThreadPoolExecutor.destroy();
monitoringThreadPoolTaskExecutor.shutdown();
Thread.sleep(60000);
logger.info("After Shut down Thread Count is " + Thread.activeCount());
```

}

Inside the tests I initialize these thread pools and submit tasks to them

`customThreadPoolExecutor.initialize();
  visibilityThreadPoolExecutor.initialize();
  monitoringThreadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
  //Code for submitting tasks`

I see that memory keeps on increasing every time I submit tasks to threadPools even though threads are shut down after calling shutdown.

What else needs to be done to release memory?

`